# Clear and Build Error

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

When I run "Clear and Build Project" I got the following errors:

> Not copying library
>   C:\Users\00035583\Documents\NetBeansProjects\commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
>   , it can't be read.
>
> Not copying library
>   C:\Users\00035583\Documents\NetBeansProjects\commons-collections4-4.1.jar
>   , it can't be read. Not copying library
>   C:\Users\00035583\Documents\NetBeansProjects\commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar
>   , it can't be read. Not copying library
>   C:\Users\00035583\Documents\NetBeansProjects\dom4j-1.6.1-sources.jar ,
>   it can't be read. Not copying library
>   C:\Users\00035583\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Kontrol
>   Paneli\dist\lib\commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar , it can't be read.

I can understand that it requires the above jars, but I don't need them, so I removed them. Can you help me understand why these errors occur?

Comment: check your project properties->libraries.Be sure that you removed all of the jar links.May be you removed codes which require those libraries but project need to compile

Comment: I checked library but it doesnt seem anything

Comment: on your project folder there is a file project.properties in nbproject folder.Open it and find all file.reference and delete all which doesn't require

Comment: I clear all broken reference in library. But when I re-execute same errors occure.

Comment: it should be netbeans problem so create new project and move your source to new project :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with re-install which ocurres error. I dont know why old jars cause so problem.